# Array of objects inside a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic

So, I have two classes: Node and Graph. In the private section of Graph class I declare this:

```
int size;
Node* n;
```

In the Graph constructor I'm trying to create a dynamic array:

```
size=1;

Node *n = new Node[size];
```

But I'm getting an error: "Access violation reading location 0xcccccd44". How can I fix it? I know that I must be doing something wrong with the array, but I have no idea what and how to fix it.

Class Graph:

```
class Graph {
    friend class Node;

    private:
        int size;
        Node* n;

    public:
        Graph();
        Graph(int, Vertex*);
        ~Graph();
        void Draw(RenderWindow &);
        void Update(RenderWindow &, GameObject &, bool);
};
```

And two constructors:

```
Graph::Graph() {
    size=1;

    Node *n = new Node[size];
}

Graph::Graph(int s, Vertex p[]) {
    size=s;
    Node *n = new Node[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        n[i].setNumer(i);
        n[i].setX(p[i].getX());
        n[i].setY(p[i].getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post more code, but I would guess you are not following [*the rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Comment: Well, there's really not much more code to add here... I'll put the code in the first post.

Comment: Did you mean to initialise the member `n`, rather than declaring a local variable with the same name? And why aren't you using `std::vector<Node>` to avoid all the problems you get with manual pointer-juggling?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `n = new Node[size];`, you are hiding your member variable `n`.

Comment: Thank you, guys! The problem was that I was declaring a local variable here instead of initializing a member... Thanks!

Comment: Use `std::vector` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are redeclaring `n` in your constructor. You got it right with `size` but not with `n`. Like this

```
Graph::Graph(int s, Vertex p[]) {
    size=s;
    n = new Node[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        n[i].setNumer(i);
        n[i].setX(p[i].getX());
        n[i].setY(p[i].getY());
    }
}
```

In your version you are initializing a local variable called `n`, which is different to the `n` declared in your class.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment before you posted the rest of your code, you are hiding your member variable `n` here:

```
Node *n = new Node[size];
^^^^^^^
```

this declares a new automatic variable `n` which will not exist after you leave your constructor and will also leak memory, just change it to this:

```
n = new Node[size];
```

As others already mentioned using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) would be easier.